# How do you format the HHVM error log output?

Tags: logging, nginx, hhvm, hiphop

I'm using HHVM with Nginx.

I like to have a certain error log format.  Specifically, with timestamp and error level with timezone offset included in error logs like:

```
 [2014-02-23 01:20:33 -0500] WARNING: File not found
```

I've managed to get timestamps into the HHVM error log with the following:

```
 hhvm.log.level = Warning
 hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
 hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
 hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
 hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
 hhvm.log.header = true
```

However, I can't find any way to format the error log output.  Currently, here is what I get for output in the HHVM error log:

```
 [Wed Feb 25 18:08:20 2015] [hphp] [6516:7f30a15ff700:4:000001] [] \nWarning: File not found:
```

Does anyone know how to modify the error log format for HHVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently hardcoded in [hhvm's source](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/util/logger.cpp).

I highly recommend [submitting a feature request to the hhvm team](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues), they're a bunch of *very* helpful people.

If you're not interested in that, you could pretty easily edit the timestamp call to include the offset, then rearrange the `snprintf()` lines to match your liking. The function you're looking for is the line starting with `std::string Logger::GetHeader() {` -- which is currently line 222.

Aside from that, you could have a cron or background process ( i.e. something like `tail -f /var/log/some/error.log |awk -F " " '{ print $1 $5 }' >> /var/log/other/error.log &` ) parse the log into the format of your liking

I realize of course, that these options while functional, are probably not ideal.

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the link to the logging code.  I'll submit a ticket with them.